Декодировать штрихкод с помощью Python
У меня есть штрихкод (шрифт EanBwrP36Tt):

точнее есть его значение, полученное при парсинге Excel файла (с использованием библиотеки openpyxl):
%!50BJ1F-idjbai!

Мне нужно из: %!50BJ1F-idjbai! - получить - 2501915839108
Все что я нагуглил, библиотеки для Python предлагают загрузить изображение в кач-ве исходника, а это мне не подходит.
Есть ли возможность с помощью Python получить нужное мне значение?

Делаете свой маппинг (например, по этим данным), а потом простую замену:
bar_mapping = {"#": 0, "$": 1, "%": 2, "&": 3, "'": 4, "(": 5, ")": 6, "*": 7, "+": 8, ",": 9,
               "a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3, "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7, "i": 8, "j": 9,
               "k": 0, "l": 1, "m": 2, "n": 3, "o": 4, "p": 5, "q": 6, "r": 7, "s": 8, "t": 9}

a = "%!50BJ1F-idjbai!"
res = "".join([str(bar_mapping.get(x, ""))
               if not x.isdigit()
               else str(x) for x in a.lower()])
print(res)


2501915839108

